# How to view the contents of a cookieJar in Golang?

Tags: cookies, go

I'm trying to view the contents of a cookieJar response from a request to google:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/cookiejar"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {

    jar, err := cookiejar.New(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    client := http.Client{Jar: jar}
    resp, err := client.Get("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Ffeature%3Dsign_in_button%26hl%3Den%26action_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26next%3D%252F%26app%3Ddesktop&service=youtube&sacu=1&passive=1209600&ignoreShadow=0&acui=0#identifier")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(resp.Cookies())

    s := ".google.com"
    u, err := url.Parse(s)
    fmt.Println(client.Jar.Cookies(u))

}
```

The response is a blank array but I can see that there are cookies being set. How do I view the contents of a cookieJar in Golang?

Comment: accounts.google.com doesn't return anything either.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not, the cookie jar in the std library is completely opaque and can be queried via (non-wildcard) URLs only.

Answer (score 0):

Although Volker is technically correct in the sense that the `net/http/cookiejar` implementation is opaque, the `http.Client.Jar` field is an interface (`http.Client.CookieJar`).

So it is possible to define and use an implementation that provides a list function or exposes a map of URL to cookies. Such an implementation should be based on the std library's implementation to leverage the security features it implements.

If there's any interest, I might provide some sample code.